How is the directory block checksum calculated in ext4?
In ext4, each block for a directory, when using classic linear directory, ends with a 12 byte "fake" dir entry that contains the following:

UUID + inode number + inode generation + the directory block up to the fake entry enclosing the checksum field

I have been trying to calculate that checksum to match what I have from a simple mkfs with a root directory with just a few files in it, and have been unable to do so.
I create a byte array that consists of the following in order:

Filesystem UUID (8 bytes)
inode number (2) as le32
inode generation (0) as le32
all of the bytes in the directory block up until the fake entry, i.e. excluding the last 12 bytes. So for a 1024-byte blocksize, the first 1012 bytes

I then pass it through crc32c and get completely different output.
I tried to do the superblock checksum as well, the trick was to do 0xffffffff-(crc32c(superblockBytes)). That did not work here.
What am I missing?
EDIT: having dug more deeply, I see that it does not do them all as a byte array, but rather checksums each. So now I do the following:

Take the checksumSeed from the superblock (which itself was generated from the original UUID bytes).
checksum that with inode number (4 bytes), get a new le32 result
checksum that with inode generation (4 bytes), get a new le32 result
checksum that with the actual 1012 bytes, get a new le32 result

That last step still doesn't work.

EDIT: So to answer your qn of if you are missing anything, idk but I found that you need to do the checksum on the dir entry for this number of bytes = blocksize - sizeof(struct ext4_dir_entry_tail)
which means you need to do a checksum on (blocksize - 12) bytes;
(I may be wrong as I do not understand ext4 enuf) After Reading through ext4.h a bit more I found that the ext4_dir_entry doesn't include a fs uuid at the start so idk why you need to do a checksum on it.
struct ext4_dir_entry {
    __le32  inode;          /* Inode number */
    __le16  rec_len;        /* Directory entry length */
    __le16  name_len;       /* Name length */
    char    name[EXT4_NAME_LEN];    /* File name */
};

struct ext4_dir_entry_tail {
    __le32  det_reserved_zero1; /* Pretend to be unused */
    __le16  det_rec_len;        /* 12 */
    __u8    det_reserved_zero2; /* Zero name length */
    __u8    det_reserved_ft;    /* 0xDE, fake file type */
    __le32  det_checksum;       /* crc32c(uuid+inum+dirblock) */
};

Function definition for calculating checksum of directory block
static void ext4_dirblock_csum_set(struct inode *inode,
             struct buffer_head *bh)
{
    struct ext4_dir_entry_tail *t;

    if (!ext4_has_metadata_csum(inode->i_sb))
        return;

    t = get_dirent_tail(inode, bh);
    if (!t) {
        warn_no_space_for_csum(inode);
        return;
    }

    t->det_checksum = ext4_dirblock_csum(inode, bh->b_data,
                     (char *)t - bh->b_data);
}

EDIT 2.0:
Ok nvm idk how ppl read the source code, I'm just utterly confused by the ext4_chksum function, like, it seems to me that it doesn't pass in the crc_seed to the crc32_update function at all and just updates it with an uninitialised shash_desc.ctx.
Then it just returns the crc_seed, like what?? am I stupid or does the code make 0 sense?
static inline u32 ext4_chksum(struct ext4_sb_info *sbi, u32 crc,
              const void *address, unsigned int length)
{
    struct {
        struct shash_desc shash;
        char ctx[4];
    } desc;

    BUG_ON(crypto_shash_descsize(sbi->s_chksum_driver)!=sizeof(desc.ctx));

    desc.shash.tfm = sbi->s_chksum_driver;
    *(u32 *)desc.ctx = crc;

    BUG_ON(crypto_shash_update(&desc.shash, address, length));

    return *(u32 *)desc.ctx;
}

And i'm even more bewildered with the way they use the container_of macro. Idk how its not giving undefined behaviour??
Like in this function, how does this even make sense?
static inline struct shash_alg *__crypto_shash_alg(struct crypto_alg *alg)
{
    return container_of(alg, struct shash_alg, base);
}

It's offsetting the alg ptr which isn't even a ptr to 'base' by -offset of base in struct shash_alg but there is no 'base' member in struct shash_alg unless somehow the program can access the mbember of a member without referencing the intermediate member.

Yeah, I struggled with it. I successfully managed to understand it in the end, and then I even rewrote it in go so that it works (and is quite readable), but it was a lot of trial and error.
